# Область видимости Lua

Tags: lua

В книге автора языка программирования **Lua** написано:

В отличие от глобальных переменных, область видимости локальной
переменной ограничена блоком, где она была объявлена. Блок — это
тело управляющей структуры, тело функции или кусок кода (файл или
строка, где переменная была объявлена).

```
-- 1 блок
do
    x = 1
end
print (x) -- переменная x из глобальной области видимости доступна!
-- Почему так происходит ? Ведь блок это место где существования переменной 
-- заканчивается... ( если я правильно понимаю суть Блок'ов)
:-> 1

-- 2 блок функции
function foo ()
    y = 2
    print (x)
    return y
end
print (foo())
-- Здесь так же...
:-> 1
:-> 2
-- переменные x, y доступны из глобальной области видимости! При 
-- том, переменная x внутри другого блока!
```

Насколько я понял, **Блок** доступен после его объявления, и мне не понятно еще вот такой код:

```
do
    function f()
        n = 'A'
        return n    
    end
end
print (n)
:-> nil

do
    function f()
        n = 'A'
        return n
    end
    f()
end
print (n)
:-> A
```

Насколько я понял, **В отличие от глобальных переменных, область видимости локальной переменной ограничена блоком, где она была объявлена. Блок — это тело управляющей структуры, тело функции или кусок кода (файл или строка, где переменная была объявлена).** - это не работает, если надо чтобы переменная было локальной то надо ее обьявлять с **local** иначе обьявления переменной внутри любого **Блока** не делает ее локальной. (если я ошибаюсь пожалуйтса обьясните с примером если можно.)

Comment: Локальная переменная в Lua это по определению переменная объявленная с local. Если не написано local то это глобальная переменная.

Comment: https://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html *"We create local variables with the **local** statement"*

Comment: Тоесть, переменная без local  она глобальная везде правильно ?

Comment: `и мне не понятно еще вот такой код: ... ` - у вас там функция просто создана но ни разу не выполнена , поэтому `n=nil`,  а если ее вызвать, как во втором случае сделано , то `n` - объявится.

Answer (score 2):

Это такая фишка Lua - глобальные переменные по умолчанию. Если переменную написать внутри блока, она будет глобальной. Чтобы она стала локальной к тому блоку внутри которого написана, нужно написать перед ней local и только тогда она станет локальной.

Если например написать local x в файле и больше ничего, то она будет локальная для файла.

Все глобальные переменные хранятся в таблице _G.

Интересный факт еще, то что локальные переменные работают быстрее, но их количество ограничено для каждого блока ~250, так как по сути они являются регистрами для виртуальной машины. (нужно всегда писать типо вот-так для скорости local sin=math.sin)